# Redirect in Django giving 302 response

Tags: python, django, django-views

What I am trying to do is prevent an authenticated user from accessing the signup page. This is what I have written.

```
def validate_request(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_active:
        print("Condition approved")
        return redirect("home:home")

def signup_view(request):
    validate_request(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentUserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("https://google.com"). #TODO: Replace it
        else:
            redirect("home:home")
    else:
        print("Got some other method: ", request.method)
        form = StudentUserSignupForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "signup_login_form.html", context=context)
```

When I test and create a new user, it gets created successfully and is redirecting fine. However, the new user created is still able to access the signup page.

I added some quick print statements at the redirect function call inside `validate_request` function and the output was

```
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/">
```

The URL it was trying to check for is already present and is correct.

I replaced the redirect to `https://google.com` instead of `home:home` and it still gave the same response.

The third thing tried was to redirect as soon as the `signup_view` function is called. That too was failing with the same response with both internal redirect and redirecting to Google.

I have been stuck on this problem for a while. I have gone through answers to similar questions but those didn't seem to help me.

*Some more details that might be useful*

Project structure is

```
Website
|
'->Website
   '->urls.py
   '-> ...
   '-> ...
'->Users
   '-> urls.py
'->Home
   '-> urls.py
```

Content of `Website/urls.py` is

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mdeditor/', include('mdeditor.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("Home.urls")),
    path('u/', include('Users.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Content of `Users/urls.py` is

```
app_name = "students"

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signup_view, name="signup"),
    path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
]
```

Content of `home/urls.py` is

```
app_name = "home"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name="home")
]
```

Python==3.8.2
Django==3.2.6

I don't know what I am missing here. It would be really helpful if you guys could point me to my mistake here.

Comment: you have to authenticate the user before using the `login` function

Comment: @AmandeepSingh An unauthenticated user should be able to access signup page. Authenticated user shouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: @PranavaMohan the function is about registering the user. I have override the function `form.save()` that first marks the student active and fills in other necessary details in the database before login the user.  Probably should add that function here as well.

Comment: why not render the signup button based on whether the user is registered or not, in the template ? Also a signed in user seeing a signup button isn't common right!

Comment: @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM singup button is not shown to the user already logged in. I have handled it already in the template. But the user would still be able to access the form via the URL directly or by going to the previous page through browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just forgot to use the response of `validate_request`:

```
def signup_view(request):
    response = validate_request(request)
    if response:
        return response
    ...
```

If there is a response object (your redirect), just return that. Otherwise go to the rest of the view.

Comment: Since it looks like you only need this on the sign up view, this should be enough. But if you need it on a lot of views, I suggest you use @Amandeep Singh's answer

Answer (score 2):

I could have checked authenticated users in view itself. But it would be better to write a custom decorator which you can use in any view. If you want to prevent any view from being accessed by logged in users then you can use the following.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from functools import wraps
from django.urls import reverse

def redirect_logged_in_users(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_active:
            return redirect(reverse("home:home"))
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then you can use this custom decorator in sign_up view

```
@redirect_logged_in_users
def sign_up(request):
    # function code
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you logout from your admin panel before testing your user CRUD
otherwise, Django will redirect you everytime since your have

```
def validate_request(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_active:
        print("Condition approved")
        return redirect("home:home")
```

I know because I am guilty...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it turns out that I wasn't following the password setup instructions provided to me by the Django registration form.

[image: django instructions on user registration password requirements]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31918326)